# How to implement OnKeyEvent for a custom class that extends webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a custom class as:

```
public final class CustomWebView extends WebView implements OnKeyListener{}
```

I am trying to implement KeyListener for this webview to get all the keyevents that happened to this webview. I tried to setOnKeyListener in CustomWebView's constructor but I am not able to ddo so. Below is my attempt to implement setOnKeyListener in public constructor:

```
this.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("MyCustomView", "Key pressed on custom view constructor: "+Integer.toString(keyCode));
            return false;
        }
});
```

I also tried to implement this as a public method as following inside the class:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("MyCustomView", "Key pressed custom view: "+Integer.toString(keyCode));
    return false;
```

Is there that I am completely missing or this cannot be done at all.

I am trying to get all events from soft keyboard.
I appreciate any help. Thank you.
    }

Comment: did you try changing from returning `false` to `true` inside `onKey()`?

Comment: Yes no change. I tried implementating dispatchKeyEvent and now I can grab DEL, and number 0 through 9 but nothing else. What would that mean?